# Rails money-rails gem getting undefined method on monetize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, currency

I'm trying to get the `money-rails` gem working, and I'm having problems... >.<

Here's the product I have the appropriate columns on:

```
class ItemAttrVal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attr_name
  belongs_to :registry_item

  monetize :price_val_cents, :allow_nil => true
  #snip
end
```

I've run the migration, and the appropriate columns are there (`price_val_cents`, and `price_val_currency`).

I've got the gem in my Gemfile, and have run `bundle install` successfully.

When I do `ItemAttrVal.new`, I get this as the first line of the error message:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `monetize' for #<Class:0x007fb489c759d0>
```

Could somebody help point out to me what simple thing I've missed?
I haven't included it anywhere as a `require` (apart from my Gemfile), but I didn't think that was needed...

Thanks!

Comment: Have you restarted your console or server since adding the gem?

Comment: Ok... That's really embarrassing... Restarted, and it worked! I thought that doing a `reload!` in the console was enough to at least get the console going?

Comment: I don't know exactly how reload! works, but this sort of makes sense because it doesn't reload the entire environment. Otherwise it would be really slow, which it's not. Since gems are loaded when the environment loads, reload! would not require any new gems that you added.

Comment: I had the same problem, even after reloading. I had to kill spring and It worked.

Comment: Same here- spring restart needed

Answer (score 3):

Based on Peter Brown's comment, you should restart the console whenever a new gem is added, or when environment variable is added or modified. Just exit and start it again, rebooting the server is also recommended.

Sometimes the problem persists, even after restart. In that case try to kill the spring server so you are starting completely fresh.